# How to update a Postgres row atomically, with a computed value that depends on the new values

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, update

I have the following table in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE avg (
    user_id INT,
    numer DOUBLE PRECISION,
    denom DOUBLE PRECISION,
    frac DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

I want to accomplish the following, and I'm having a hard time getting this into one query. Basically I want to be able to update some averages atomically, by separately updating the numerator and denominator, then compute and update the average `frac` in the same operation, based on the new values:

1. Given params `a` and `b`, I want to find the row for a given `user_id`, then I want to do `numer += a` and `denom += b`, and calculate `frac = numer / denom` from the new values of `numer` and `denom`, then update the values of `numer`, `denom`, and `frac` in this row.
2. However, if there is no row for the requested `user_id`, *or* if there is a row, but the values of `numer` and `denom` are null, then I want to assume that the value of those sums is zero, in other words a new row should be inserted into the table, or an update operation should be performed if there is a row but the values are null, with the result being to set `numer = a`, `denom = b`, and `frac = a / b` for the `user_id`.
3. I want to ensure this all happens atomically.

There may be multiple numerators and denominators in a given table, hence the need to be able to do both insert (if the row doesn't exist) or update (if the row exists but the initial values of a specific numerator/denominator pair are null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is *not* to store redundant data in a database. My solution would be

```
CREATE TABLE real_avg (
    user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    numer double precision,
    denom double precision
);

CREATE VIEW avg
AS SELECT user_id, numer, denom,
          numer / denom AS frac
   FROM real_avg;
```

Then you can perform your desired operation as follows:

```
INSERT INTO avg (user_id, numer, denom)
   VALUES (1, 100, 50)
ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE
SET numer = avg.numer + EXCLUDED.numer,
    denom = avg.denom + EXCLUDED.denom;
```

If you insist on using a redundant table column, use a generated column that is automatically updated:

```
CREATE TABLE real_avg (
    user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    numer double precision,
    denom double precision,
    frac double precision GENERATED ALWAYS AS (numer / denom) STORED
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful!